# Why would react-router with url params won't work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Somehow this [route /article/:id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTfks.png) does not work properly, and I don't know why.

I'll also add the code, it looks like this:

```
export const RootRouter = () => {
  const routes = [
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <React.Fragment>Main</React.Fragment>,
    },
    {
      path: "/articles",
      element: <React.Fragment>Articles</React.Fragment>,
    },
    {
      path: "/article/:id",
      element: <Article />,
    }
  ];

  return useRoutes(routes);
};
```

I'm using `react-router@6` browser router, can anyone guess where I made a mistake?

And App component just in case

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { RootRouter } from "@containers/index";
import "./App.scss";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
        <RootRouter />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What isn't working? Can you [edit] to clarify what any specific issue is that you have? I don't see any overt issue with the code you've shared.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided, it seems that you are using react-router-v6 library for client-side routing in your React application.

Regarding the issue with the /article/:id route not working properly, there could be several reasons for this. Here are some suggestions:

Make sure you have imported the useRoutes hook from the react-router-dom library.
Check if you have defined the Article component correctly and passed the id parameter to it.
Make sure that you are passing the id parameter correctly in the URL when navigating to the /article/:id route. You can use the Link component from react-router-dom to navigate to this route and pass the id parameter in the URL.
Verify that you have set up the server to handle the /article/:id route correctly and to serve the appropriate data based on the id parameter.
Here's an example of how you can navigate to the /article/:id route with the Link component and pass the id parameter in the URL:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Articles() {
  const articles = [
    { id: 1, title: "Article 1" },
    { id: 2, title: "Article 2" },
    { id: 3, title: "Article 3" },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Articles</h1>
      <ul>
        {articles.map((article) => (
          <li key={article.id}>
            <Link to={`/article/${article.id}`}>{article.title}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This will create a list of articles with links that navigate to the /article/:id route with the appropriate id parameter in the URL.